# IF statement- error 1004 [Vlookup file returns zero]

Tags: if-statement, combobox, textbox, vlookup

I am creating a product database with data from excel Column (2nos). 1 column contains product description and another price.

A combo-box gets filled in with the products data (search as you type) and when a button is clicked, a textbox displays the price.

So the problem now is that, sometimes there might be products which is not on the database, and when button is clicked the program ends. tried to go around using IF function. didn't work out as expected.

I am a noob to this. Please help.

```
Dim ProductNa As Range
Dim ProducPr As Object
Private Sub LowPriceBtn_Click()
    Set ProductNa = Worksheets("Pdata").Range("A2:B7400")
    ProducPr = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ProBox1.Value, ProductNa, 2, False)
    If ProducPr <> 0 Then
    proRate1.Text = ProducPr
    Else
    proRate1.Text = "Nothing available in database"
    End If
    End Sub
```

The code above doesnt work.

This is the one which used to work:

```
Private Sub LowPriceBtn_Click()
Set ProductNa = Worksheets("Pdata").Range("A2:B7400")
proRate1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ProBox1.Value, ProductNa, 2, False)
```

This does work. But when Vlookup returns no value, program crashes.

PS: proRate1- Textbox name, probox1- combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that can inspire you develop your code.

> ```
>  1. Create a new module 
>  2. Paste code bellow
> ```

```
Function MyVLOOKUP(p_value_search As Range, p_matrix As Range, p_col_return As Integer)
'= MyVLOOKUP(E4;Banks!$B$2:$Q$10563;9)
v_value_search = p_value_search.Value
For x = 1 To p_matrix.Rows.Count
  If v_value_search = p_matrix.Cells(x, 1).Value Then
     v_resp = p_matrix.Cells(x, p_col_return).Value
     Exit For
  End If
Next
MyVLOOKUP = v_resp
End Function
```

> ```
>  3. Go back to the worksheet and insert into a cell the code equal to 
>  the VLOOKUP function.  example: = MyVLOOKUP(E4;Banks!$B$2:$Q$10563;9)
> ```
>
> This function doesn't return ZERO or #N/D when doesn't found value. 
>   I Hope to help you.